# MDX query with TOPCOUNT between date range returning a top with some empty values

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap, olap-cube, mondrian

I'm using a MDX query to get the top 10 liked Products between two dates. Oddly, the result is composed by some Products with likes within that date range, and some without any likes at all. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Likes] } ON COLUMNS,
{ TOPCOUNT([Products].[Name].Members, 10, [Measures].[Likes]) } ON ROWS
FROM [Likes]
WHERE ( [Date].[2014].[3].[29]:[Date].[2014].[4].[5] )
```

Here are the results:

```
               [Measures].[Likes]
[Product].[XX]
[Product].[XX]
[Product].[XX]          139
[Product].[XX]
[Product].[XX]           1
[Product].[XX]
[Product].[XX]
[Product].[XX]          125
[Product].[XX]          111
[Product].[XX]           1
```

If I change the top limit to 20, for example, the results will have more products with likes but also with more empty ones, and not ordered (like a top usually is).

Using NON EMPTY makes the query return only 5 results instead of 10, and still not ordered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

`SELECT
{ [Measures].[Likes] } ON 0,
 Head(ORDER([Products].[Name].Members,[Measures].[Likes], DESC), 10)  ON 1
FROM [Likes]
WHERE ( [Date].[2014].[3].[29]:[Date].[2014].[4].[5] )`

Comment: Wow, this works, thanks!. But I can't understand why TOPCOUNT doesn't. Any clue? and, is the performance of HEAD(ORDER similar to TOPCOUNT?

Comment: Like the BottomCount function, the TopCount function always breaks the hierarchy. Source http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792.aspx

Head is faster (source http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a3d0e01a-100f-4308-b108-54837f3f0ce5/question-regarding-mdx-performance-topcounthead-functions)

Comment: If I get it right, that means that it will not take the hierarchy in consideration right, and will order by the numeric expression specified. But in my example, it is not sorting by the numeric expression. What am I missing here?

And this only occurs when the dates are in different months.